# UIHostingController and navigationController

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

Default swift project with view controller embedded in navigationController and pushing to next UIHostingController.

How to call navigationController?.popViewController from SimpleView ?

ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button?.addTarget(self,
                      action: #selector(showNewSwiftUIController),
                      for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func showNewSwiftUIController() {
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView:SimpleView())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

SwiftUI:

```
struct SimpleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SimpleView")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First.
Have you tried?

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode> // reference
```

Then on your body call:

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

If that does not work:

I will suggest you either pass the navigation controller as an optional variable into the View as a reference and access from there.
Other option and maybe a healthier option is to pass a "callback" variable from the parent to the childView to dismiss the view (you need to save the Navigation as a variable to keep track)

Last option (Not recommended)

```
if var topController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
        
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.navigationController.popViewController(animated:true)

 }
```